# Highcharts drilldown on area chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

When drilldown is used on stacked area charts, the event is triggered based on the series closest to the mouse, not based on the area clicked. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

In other words, can I make all of the blue area trigger series 1's drilldown and all of the green trigger series 2's drilldown?

```js
$(function() {
    series1 = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64].map(point => ({
        y: point,
        drilldown: true,
    }))
    series2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].map(point => ({
        y: point,
        drilldown: true,
    }))

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            events: {
                drilldown: (e) => console.log(e.point.series.name)
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                trackByArea: true
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        series: [{
            data: series1,
            type: 'area',
            color: 'blue'
        }, {
            data: series2,
            type: 'area',
            color: 'green'
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I think this may be small Highcharts bug, it should trigger correct area when you are using trackByArea: true. If you think the same you may report this problem on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: @Grzegorz Blachliński OK, thanks, will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround for Highcharts 4.2:

The original event actually has a reference for a certain element of the SVG, so we can use this instead of the event passed into the drilldown function.

Requires lodash and jQuery:

```
drilldown: function(e) {
  index = _.findIndex(this.series, (series) =>
    $(e.originalEvent.path[1]).children().is((series.area || {}).element)
  )
  console.log(this.series[index].name)
}
```